# Rake task to update a column value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am writing a rake task to update the value in a specific column in a table. When I run the task, I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant FirstLookSubscription
```

Here is the rake task code:

```
namespace :first_look_db do
  desc "Adds one month to the Look Subscription"
  FirstSubscription.where(subscription_state: 'active').each do |t|
        t.update_attribute :next_billing_check, '2013-9-10'

  end
end
```

I am new to rake tasks, and I don't want to do this as a migration. Any advice would be great!

also note: when I run this in the rails console, it executes without a problem, my biggest issue is turning it into a rake task so that our lead dev can run it

Comment: What did you type in to run the task? What does your `FirstSubscription` model look like (`app/models/first_subscription.rb`)?

Comment: run task:
    bundle exec rake first_look_db

    attr_accessible :next_billing_check, :start_date, :expiration_date, :subscription_state

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really need a task name. The `namespace` gives the namespace of the task, but declare a task by name and import the environment so it can find your ActiveRecords:

```
namespace :first_look_db do
  desc "Adds one month to the Look Subscription"

  task :add_month_to_look_sub => :environment do
    FirstSubscription.where(subscription_state: 'active').each do |t|
      t.update_attribute :next_billing_check, '2013-9-10'

    end
  end
end
```

This would go into a file called `lib/tasks/first_look_db.rake`. The task is called by:

```
rake first_look_db:add_month_to_look_sub
```

or possibly:

```
bundle exec rake first_look_db:add_month_to_look_sub
```

If the first one tells you to do so. You can name the `namespace` and `task` however you wish in the `rake` file. I just picked some names that seemed to make sense to me from what you had.