# Change a table's column values based on the value in a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I change the values of a column in a migration, where the I need to modify the values based on what they are? The column I want to change contains an array of strings. I want to modify some of the string elements to some other string, but only if the string element meet certain conditions. Sometimes the array will be empty.

The `change_column` method allows to change the type of the column and pass in options, but I would like a flexible way to modify values based on what they are. Is there an Active Record Migrations method that allows this flexibility?

Comment: Not exactly a migration, but you can simply do an update all within a migration file.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update

Comment: `connection.execute(%q{your SQL goes here})`

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the task you can run directly from console or create a rake task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823005/rake-task-to-update-a-column-value